# jquery call by id in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a DOM like:

```
<div className="three wide column">
   <div className="ui small progress" id={data.url}>
       <div className="bar"></div>
   </div>

</div>
```

and I am calling a jquery for this progress bar like:

```
$(`#${data.url}`).progress({
    percent: 72
 });
```

But its giving me error saying `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:`

What is wrong in here ??

Comment: What is this id `{data.url}` are you using angular?

Comment: why is `#` following by `$` ?

Comment: `data.url` gives me string of url which I am setting as id

Comment: use this `$('#\\{data\\.url\\}')`

Comment: Then you should have added `reactjs` tag in your question. Just did that

Comment: store the `${data.url}` value into another variable and use that variable in `jquery` selector

Answer (score 0):

```
`#${data.url}` is ES6(EcmaScript 6) syntax.
```

Right now there is no full support of ES6 in browsers.

Use

```
$("#"+data.url).progress({
    percent: 72
 });
```

or use a tool like babel to build your code before using deploying it.

Hope it will work.

You can read more about ES6 template strings [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score -1):

even though i don't know reactjs, the syntax seems inconsistent.
In html markup:

1. There is no "$" before the expression "{data.url}"
2. The expression is not wrapped into '"'

I'd expect the following markup:

```
<div className="ui small progress" id="${data.url}">
```

Hope this helps.